# Adding a vertical reference line to a plot on a categorical axis

Tags: r, plotly

In the plot below, I would like to add a custom error bar extending to the right of the bar. I'm halfway there, as shown below, in other words, I have the horizontal line, but I can't figure out how to add the vertical bar to the end of the skinny line as shown in green below. Does anyone have any ideas on how to accomplish this?

```
library(magrittr)
library(plotly)

df <- data.frame(grp = c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E") %>% as.factor,
           val = c(11:15)) %>% 
df %>%
  plot_ly(x = ~val,
          y = ~grp,
          type = "bar") %>% 
  add_segments(xend = 20,
               yend = ~grp)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may add a marker to the end of the segment.
In addition you can group the legends of segement and marker together, so there are hidden/shown at the same time when toggling legend items.

**Code**

```
 df %>%
  plot_ly(x = ~val,
          y = ~grp,
          type = "bar") %>% 
  add_segments(xend = 20,
               yend = ~grp,
               legendgroup = "g1") %>%
  add_markers(x = 20,
              # style marker
              marker = list(
                symbol = "line-ns-open",
                size = 15,
                line = list(
                  width = 5
                )),
              # combine legends
              legendgroup = "g1",
              showlegend = F)
```

**Plot**
[image]

Comment: Thanks so much @tamtam. One follow-up question that I recognize is out of the scope of the original question, do you know how I hide just the legend entry for the bar color (i.e., trace 0), while keeping the legend entry for the error bar (i.e., trace 1) I've tried adding 'showlegend = F' to the first 'plot_ly' statement, but that hides the entire legend.

Comment: The first showlegend seems to overwrite the rest of the code. You may need to define `showlegend` for each trace and add `%>% layout(showlegend = T)` at the end. `df %>%   plot_ly(x = ~val, y = ~grp, type = "bar", showlegend = F) %>%  add_segments(xend = 20, yend = ~grp, legendgroup = "g1", showlegend = T) %>% add_markers(x = 20, marker = list(symbol = "line-ns-open", size = 15, line = list(width = 5)), legendgroup = "g1", showlegend = F) %>% layout(showlegend = T)`

Comment: That did it. Thanks very much!